# Tablets - Revisited: Usage and orientation

Tags: tablet

This is a topic which has been done before, but all the answers I could find were from a while ago:

1 - Are Tablets still being actively used ?

2 - What orientation are they being used in ?

(I'll add the links to previous answers later)

Answer (score 1):

In 2013, there were 660 *million* active tablets throughout the world.
Today there are 1.26 **billion**, an increase of 88.62%.
Forecasts predict that number to grow to 1.28 in 2021.

[image]

Surveys have found that tablet users generally PREFER landscape, although this option is not always available in many apps, or in low-end budget tablets lacking gyroscope hardware to auto-rotate the screen.

http://www.tuaw.com/2013/06/26/the-majority-of-ipad-owners-prefer-landscape-over-portrait/

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  (Although I notice the little asterisk in the first chart so the hard data stops in 2016), which in technology years is quite a long time ago.